# using mat-sort-header on a column which lists the length of a subarray property for each row

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Let's say I have a MatTableDataSource created using the following array:

```
[ {propA: 'something', propB: ['a', 'b', 'c']}, {propA: 'somethingElse', propB: ['d', 'e', 'f']}]
```

As we can see this is an array of objects where **propB** is an array.

Now let's say for each element of the outer array I have want to have a row in my table with two columns : propA(which simply lists the value for this property) and propBCount(which lists the length of the value array for this property).

Following is the column definition for the second column that I want :

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="propBCount">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Total Items </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.propB.length}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

How can I use mat-sort-header for this column?

Comment: the "easy" way is add a new property of each object of your array:`this.obj.forEach(x=>{x.totalITems=x.propB.length}`. So use this property to display and sort

Answer (score 0):

From the [Table | Angular Material (Sorting section) documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting):

> Note that if the data properties do not match the column names, or if a more complex data property accessor is required, then a custom sortingDataAccessor function can be set to override the default data accessor on the MatTableDataSource.

1. Apply `matSort` directive in `mat-table` HTML element.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
  ...
</table>
```

2. Apply `MatSort` to `dataSource`.
3. Implment the custom sorting logic to `dataSource.sortingDataAccessor`.

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) matSort: MatSort;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.sort = this.matSort;
  this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (data: any, sortHeaderId: string) => {
    if (sortHeaderId == 'propBCount') return data.propB.length;

    return data[sortHeaderId as keyof typeof data];
  };
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thlmho?file=src/main.ts)

References: [Angular mat-table sort example: Adding sorting to the material table](https://www.angularjswiki.com/material/mat-table-sort/)